# String processing in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Assume to have the following Excel table

[image]

I'm trying to write a Macro in VBA which scans the cells in the routing column and spreads the substrings into the other columns. So this should be the final result

[image]

Potentially if the algorithm finds n substrings in the main string under the column Rtg it should fill n columns with the substrings.

Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will be easier to help if you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54598681/edit) to show us what you've tried so far. Also can you explain why text to columns won't work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can parse using the **dash** character:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        arr = Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, "-")
        Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

The code will err if it encounters an empty cell prematurely.  To avoid this use:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, 2).Value
        If v <> "" Then
            arr = Split(v, "-")
            Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the macro works but when it runs it gives me an error on the last line "Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr" saying "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Thank you, the macro works but when it runs it gives me an error on the last line "Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr" saying "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: @DavideTarsitano  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

As outlined [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7), you can use `Text to Columns`:

> Select the cell or column that contains the text you want to split.
>
> Select Data > Text to Columns.
>
> In the Convert Text to Columns Wizard, select Delimited > Next.
>
> Select the Delimiters for your data. You'd want to put a `-` in the "Other" area.
>
> Select Next.
>
> Select the Column data format or use what Excel chose for you.
>
> Select the Destination, which is where you want the split data to
>   appear on your worksheet.
>
> Select Finish.

Comment: Thanks, can I record a Macro for this and do it for any row?

Comment: @DavideTarsitano - Yes you can. You can also highlight all the rows you need it to run on, and do it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sub for operating on the current active cell.

```
Sub splitCell()
Dim cellSplit As Variant
Dim nextColumn As Long

nextColumn = 1
cellSplit = Split(ActiveCell.Value2, "-")
For Each Item In cellSplit
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, nextColumn).Value2 = Item
    nextColumn = nextColumn + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions appear to deal with leading hyphens correctly.

This should deal with leading/trailing/double hyphens on the currently selected cells within one column. The caveat is that the individual substrings should not contain spaces.

```
Sub splitHyphens()

    Dim i As Long, sel As Range, vals As Variant

    For Each sel In Selection

        vals = Split(Application.Trim(Replace(sel.Value, "-", Space(1))), Space(1))
        sel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vals) + 1) = vals


    Next sel

End Sub
```